# golang convert excel sheet to a struct

Tags: excel, go

I tried to use https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx and https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize
I success to read from excel file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
)

func main() {
    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("Book1.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // Get value from cell by given worksheet name and axis.
    cell, err := f.GetCellValue("Sheet1", "B2")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(cell)
    // Get all the rows in the Sheet1.
    rows, err := f.GetRows("Sheet1")
    for _, row := range rows {
        for _, colCell := range row {
            fmt.Print(colCell, "\t")
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

put I want to convert data from excel to Array of defined struct

example

```
type InvoiceSheet struct {
    amount string
    item   string
   
}

var invoices []InvoiceSheet

err := excel.READMETHOD('path of file', &invoices)
```

then I can iterate invoices

Comment: Hi I edited my answer. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not interiorized with that module, but looking at the source code I see there's a "Columns()" function you can use to get the values you need.

```
// Columns return the current row's column values.
func (rows *Rows) Columns() ([]string, error)
```

https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/master/rows.go

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any directly serialization is supported (not familiar with the package) so then why you wouldn't traverse your spreadsheet and initialize struct by struct and append it to a slice.

If your schema is known in advance you could define a map with your categories and use them as a reference point e.g.

```golang
columns:= map[string]string{"Id" : "A1", "Item" : "B1", "Amount" : "C1"}
```

Start a loop within you will parse next rows to extract your struct values.

```golang
func (m *MergeCell) GetCellValue() string
```

Do it until  its something to read, maybe until there is `Id` a not empty string.
I've just came up with a possible way to implement it nicer.

Instead, map[string]string use some map[string]Cell.

That Cell would look like that:

```golang
type struct Cell {
    column : string
    row : int
}
func (c Cell) str() {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", c.column, c.row)
}
```

It appears they have some column [iterator](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/324f87bcaed9ec775c0b79627956a093ad481d36/rows_test.go) implemented that can help you as well.

Here is example that basically solves your task (I omitted error handling to make it shorter).

```golang
    const sheet2 = "SheetName"

    f, _ := OpenFile(filepath.Join("test", "Book1.xlsx"))

    rows, _ := f.Rows(sheet2)

    var collectedRows [][]string
    for rows.Next() {
        columns, _:= rows.Columns()
        // here init your struct and append it to slice as described above
    }
```

More examples with rows you'll find in tests files e.g. [here](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/324f87bcaed9ec775c0b79627956a093ad481d36/rows_test.go).

Now it's your turn. Good luck!